# Simple javascript Question (not simple for me)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please correct my code here.  It works well in most browsers but I get an error in ie7.  I'm sure it's a syntax thing:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".testimonail-label").addClass("-webkit-animation");
$(".banner h2").addClass("-webkit-animation");
$(".banner .test-name").addClass("-webkit-animation");    
};
```

Comment: im not sure what you are trying to do, what are you trying to do?

Comment: And what error do you get? "an error" isn't very illuminating.

Comment: why are you adding a class on document.ready? just add those classes in the html markup at design time. If you need to change those classes at runtime, on the client, in response to client-side events, then you use JQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: As you have a syntax error, I'm pretty sure id *does not* work in most browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a ')'

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".testimonail-label").addClass("-webkit-animation");
$(".banner h2").addClass("-webkit-animation");
$(".banner .test-name").addClass("-webkit-animation");    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

On the last line you forgot to close out the call to `ready`:

```
};
```

should be

```
});
```